# Adjust content in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

Hello to all I created a UIScrollView that shows a series of UIView that represent graifici according to your entry ...

The multiplication of view was performed using a FOR loop

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < value.count; i ++) {
    UILabel *valueX_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPadding, self.scrollChart.frame.size.height-30, 50, 30)];

    NSString *valueText = [value objectAtIndex:i];

    valueX_label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", valueText];
    valueX_label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    valueX_label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:9];
    valueX_label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    valueX_label.numberOfLines = 2;
    [self.scrollChart addSubview:valueX_label];

    xPadding += valueX_label.frame.size.width;

    self.scrollChart.contentSize = CGSizeMake(xPadding, self.scrollChart.frame.size.height);


    _backgroundBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(valueX_label.center.x - 20 , 13, 40, (self.scrollChart.frame.size.height - valueX_label.frame.size.height) -10)];
    _backgroundBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    _backgroundBar.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
    _backgroundBar.alpha = .1;
    [self.scrollChart addSubview:_backgroundBar];}
```

Now I have a problem ... After entering the paging of ScrollView I have some display problems, ie each size page a few columns as you can see from the pictures ...

[image]

I need each page displays only six columns at a time ... you can help me in any way?

Wrong pagination
Ok pagination

[image]

Comment: To be responsive to the device, do you need 6 columns, or N columns until the superview width is exceeded?

Comment: What I would like is that on every page there are 6 columns ... or a number that can vary at will ... the problem is that I can not center the columns each time you change the page

Comment: What do you mean by page, is it a UIScrollView with paging? Can you post a picture of what you want it to look like (1st page and nth page)?

Comment: is the ScrollView has paging ... as you can see in the first picture and the last column 'instead cut into the second picture appears to be the whole layout. would that not every cut his column page

Comment: Should the y axis appear on each page?

Comment: Yes, the Y axis appears on every page ... Only the X-axis runs in ScrollView